# Why does OpenGL show black screen instead of a Lagrange polynomial?

Tags: opengl

I'm developing with a Visual Studio to display a Lagrange polynomial  in OpenGL with a data set.

But my result is always black screen, what should I do?

To initialize, we used an initialization function called init_func.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;

int WINDOW_WIDTH = 640;
int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 480;



void init_func() {   //to init the func
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    gluOrtho2D(-10.0, 10.0, -10.0, 10.0); 
}



#define DATA_POINT_COUNT 21


#define DRAW_POINT_COUNT 2001


double data_points[DATA_POINT_COUNT][2] = {
    {3.0, 3.0},
    {3.36916, 3.32853},
    {3.81762, 3.54927},
    {4.30005, 3.66145},
    {4.78893, 3.67304},
    {5.28977, 3.59043},
    {5.75728, 3.43162},
    {6.20311, 3.21496},
    {6.64178, 2.97961},
    {7.0973, 2.97166},
    {7.0787, 3.44959},
    {6.8015, 3.85772},
    {6.40887, 4.16111},
    {5.94999, 4.35273},
    {5.46298, 4.4314},
    {4.96587, 4.40222},
    {4.48486, 4.27155},
    {4.04224, 4.05287},
    {3.64189, 3.75511},
    {3.29706, 3.39767},
    {3.0, 3.0},
};


double lagrange_function(double x, double y, double t, double* points, int count) {
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        double numerator = 1, denominator = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            if (j != i) {
                numerator *= (t - points[j * 2]);
                denominator *= (points[i * 2] - points[j * 2]);
            }
        }
        result += (numerator / denominator) * points[i * 2 + 1];
    }
    return result;
}


void DisplayFunc() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    double t = 0.0;
    double delta = 1.0 / (DRAW_POINT_COUNT - 1);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (int i = 0; i < DRAW_POINT_COUNT; i++) {
        double x = lagrange_function(0, 0, t, &data_points[0][0], DATA_POINT_COUNT);
        double y = lagrange_function(0, 0, t, &data_points[0][1], DATA_POINT_COUNT);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        t += delta;
    }

    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();

}

  
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        init_func();
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
        glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
        glutCreateWindow("Testing OpenGL Installation");
        glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
        glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glutDisplayFunc(&DisplayFunc);
        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: lol, try to show it first with something simpler than gl, after that gl.

Comment: 1) You can't call OpenGL commands before the window is opened. init_func must be after `glutCreateWindow`. 2) Have you checked if the result points of the `lagrange_function` are in the display range? You set the projection twice (although the one from `init_func` isn't doing anything at the moment), but the second `glOrtho` sets the visible area to [-1,1] and x and y, so all points outside of that aren't displayed.